# I am stuck in grub

Tags: linux, windows-7, ubuntu, boot, grub

Ok , i was running windows 7 dual boot with ubuntu , everything was fine.I tried to install windows 10 (while dual booting) i ran setup.exe everything went fine it installed about 30% , it restarted (as part of installation) then instead of grub asking me which to run it just showed `Partition not found` and entered rescue mode. I know there was some problem 
I tried `ls` it show one hardisk and 4 partition (`hd0,msdos5 . Hd0,msdos3 . hd0,msdos2 . hd0,msdos1`) it tried `set prefix=<diskname>/boot/grub` and `insmod normal` but it showed unknown filesystem cuz ubuntu use ext4, windows is still under installation but i don't know how to do anything (basically booting into winloader) , i currently have pendrive unavailable. Is there any way I can boot into any os or fix pc without pendrive

## I still don't have pendrive

Comment: Sorry but i live in India so I cannot answer most of the American and European cuz itz night here so it will take one day to reply

Comment: Windows updates are known to wipe GRUB. Just finish the Windows update, boot into Linux with a USB again and reinstall GRUB.